# R: How can I combine several datasets together

Tags: r

For example, I have two datasets, one is AUD and one is CAD.(Both are 412*37)
How can I create an array (say "fx") containing both datasets("AUD" and "CAD"),and later I can use data = fx[1] instead of data = AUD.

Comment: I am guessing what you want is `names = list(AUD = AUD, CAD = CAD)` but it's hard to be sure from your question. I don't think an "array" is going to do what you want.

Comment: @user3114046 the "list" doesn't work :( I edited my question and hopefully it will be easier to answer. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Still unsure about the question...if you use a list called `names` you would reference the contents by `names[[1]]`, `names[[2]]`, etc. What are your datasets, since R does not have a type called dataset? Dataframes?

Comment: you are describing lists, uncle cat

Comment: You can indeed combine several data sets together using a list: `fx <- list(AUD, CAD)` will give you a list `fx` of length 2 with `AUD` being the first and `CAD` being the second element. You then can use, say the first element by using: `fx[[1]]`. Note the double `[[` here that are neccessary to retrieve a single element as opposed to a slice of the list.

Comment: @user3114046 names[[1]] works! Thank you so much!

Comment: @tophcito thank you so much for your answer! [[ is exactly where my problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are describing a list.

```
AUD=data.frame(matrix(1:20,4,5))
CAD=data.frame(matrix(1:20,5,4, byrow=TRUE))
fx=list(CAD,AUD)
fx
fx[[1]]
fx[[2]]
```

You can also name elements of a list like this.

```
fx=list("CAD"=CAD,"AUD"=AUD)
fx$CAD    
fx$AUD
```

Comment: @unclecat Glad that worked for you. As the questioner you get to choose best answer and you can always up vote good suggestions.